# R Indexing a matrix to use in plot coordinates

Tags: r, matrix, plot, igraph

I'm trying to plot a temporal social network in R. My approach is to create a master graph and layout for all nodes. Then, I will subset the graph based on a series of vertex id's. However, when I do this and layout the graph, I get completely different node locations. I think I'm either subsetting the layout matrix incorrectly. I can't locate where my issue is because I've done some smaller matrix subsets and everything seems to work fine.

I have some example code and an image of the issue in the network plots.

```
library(igraph)

# make graph
g <- barabasi.game(25)




# make graph and set some aestetics 
set.seed(123)
l <- layout_nicely(g)
V(g)$size <- rescale(degree(g), c(5, 20))
V(g)$shape <- 'none'
V(g)$label.cex <- .75
V(g)$label.color <- 'black'

E(g)$arrow.size = .1

# plot graph

dev.off()

par(mfrow = c(1,2), 
    mar = c(1,1,5,1))


plot(g, layout = l, 
     main = 'Entire\ngraph')


# use index & induced subgraph

v_ids <- sample(1:25, 15, F)
sub_l <- l[v_ids, c(1,2)]
sub_g <- induced_subgraph(g, v_ids)


# plot second graph
plot(sub_g, layout = sub_l,
     main = 'Sub\ngraph')
```

[image]

The vertices in the second plot should match layout of those in the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you set the random seed *after* you generated the graph,
so we cannot exactly reproduce your result. I will use the same code but
with `set.seed` before the graph generation. This makes the result look
different than yours, but will be reproducible.

When I run your code, I do not see exactly the same problem as you are 
showing.

### Your code (with `set.seed` moved and `scales` added)

```
library(igraph)
library(scales)            # for rescale function

# make graph
set.seed(123)
g <- barabasi.game(25)

# make graph and set some aestetics 
l <- layout_nicely(g)
V(g)$size <- rescale(degree(g), c(5, 20))
V(g)$shape <- 'none'
V(g)$label.cex <- .75
V(g)$label.color <- 'black'
E(g)$arrow.size = .1
## V(g)$names = 1:25

# plot graph
dev.off()

par(mfrow = c(1,2), 
    mar = c(1,1,5,1))

plot(g, layout = l, 
     main = 'Entire\ngraph')

# use index & induced subgraph
v_ids <- sort(sample(1:25, 15, F))
sub_l <- l[v_ids, c(1,2)]
sub_g <- induced_subgraph(g, v_ids)

# plot second graph
plot(sub_g, layout = sub_l,
     main = 'Sub\ngraph', vertex.label=V(sub_g)$names)
```

[image: Graph with positions preserved, but not labels]

When I run *your code*, both graphs have nodes in the same 
positions. That is not what I see in the graph in your question. 
I suggest that you run just this code and see if you don't get 
the same result (nodes in the same positions in both graphs). 
The only difference between the two graphs in my version is the
node labels. When you take the subgraph, it renumbers the nodes 
from 1 to 15 so *the labels* on the nodes disagree. You can fix 
this by storing the node labels in the graph before taking the 
subgraph. Specifically, add `V(g)$names = 1:25` immediately after 
your statement `E(g)$arrow.size = .1`. Then run *the whole thing*
again, starting at `set.seed(123)`.  This will preserve the 
original numbering as the node labels.

[image: Graph with node labels preserved]

The graph looks slightly different because the new, sub-graph 
does not take up all of the space and so is stretched to use 
up the empty space.

Answer (score -1):

Possible fast way around: draw the same graph, but color nodes and vertices that you dont need in color of your background. Depending on your purposes it can suit you.